# Third substring from the end in Google Big Query

Tags: string, google-bigquery, sql

I use standard sql and want to extract third substring from the end.

```
Example Input: "Search-site-variable-brand-0-city-none-18053517"
Output: "city"
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "second substring"?! `city` looks like a third substring to me. I am thinking that you might meant to skip digit based substrings? just thinking aloud

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks, I edited the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to point out that if you plan to apply this transformation to multiple columns, it may be useful to pull the logic into a UDF. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SecondSubstringFromEnd(s STRING) AS ((
  SELECT arr[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) - 3)]
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(s, '-') AS arr
  )
));

WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 'Search-site-variable-brand-0-city-none-18053517' AS str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a-b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'w-x-yyy-z'
)
SELECT
  str,
  SecondSubstringFromEnd(str) AS second_substring_from_end
FROM Input;
```

Comment: Failed to save view. No support for CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION statements inside views

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
WITH data AS(
  select "Search-site-variable-brand-0-city-none-18053517" as Input
)

SELECT
  CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(Input, '-')) > 3 THEN SPLIT(Input, '-')[OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(Input, '-')) - 3)] END word
FROM data
```

It returns `NULL` in case the string has no split, such as empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Few more variations for BigQuery Standard SQL:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS(
  SELECT 'Search-site-variable-brand-0-city-none-18053517' AS Input UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Second-substring-from-the-end-in-Google-BigQuery' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bigQuery-assign-a-value-to-table-1-based-on-table-2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Error-Message-Too-many-sources-provided-15285-Limit-is-10000' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Google-Bigquery-data-import-from-Google-Analytics-360' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bigquery-Partitioning-data-past-2000-limit'
)
SELECT
  Input,
  REVERSE(SPLIT(REVERSE(Input), '-')[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)]) AS Output_1,
  ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(Input, '-'))[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)] AS Output_2
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The "ARRAY_REVERSE" function works wonders in this scenario.

```
with input AS 
(
 SELECT "Search-site-variable-brand-0-city-none-18053517" AS to_reverse_string 
)

SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(to_reverse_string, "-"))[SAFE_OFFSET(2)]
FROM input
```